# What kind of algorithm would I need to compute a name that equals a number?

Tags: python

For instance A =1, B = 2 ... Z = 26
The name is auto generated and must equal lets say 200 with the sum of the letters.
e.g.

```
 A = 1
 AB = 3 etc
```

What steps would be taken in creating a function to create an array of auto generated strings that has a value of 200?

How would this be done in Python?

Comment: Do some research first. Find a way to break the string down letter-by-letter, assign each letter to its numerical value, then create a function that adds it all up.

Comment: @Matthew, may I ask why you need such alg?

Answer (score 2):

You want to generate a string under some constraints.
And this is kind of optimisation problem. However we don't need to hire any machine learning here.

One possible solution might look like this (sorry, no python, just pseudo code)

1. `name = ""` #initialize name variable
2. `place = selectPlaceWhereToInsertNextCharacter(name)`
3. `char = selectNextRandomCharacter()`
4. update `name` putting `char` in `place`
5. If value of ```name`` is < 200, goto 2

Comments:

- Function `selectNextRandomCharacter` must select next character which value is less than remaining space in built so far name.
  Let's say your current name is `"zzz"`so the value of it is `174`. Next letter you select can not be greater than `200 - 174`. Othewise you will overflow.
  To do this - just select next integer within appropriate range and map it to char.
- `selectPlaceWhereToInsertNextCharacter(name)` it just selects where you will put next character. For example if name is `"pawel"` there are 6 plces where you could mix in new letter. This is because I assumed that name must be quite random.
- value of name can be checked using such python `sum(map(lambda x: ord(x)-64, name))`

Comment: Please see updated question, I'm trying to create an array of strings that's auto generated and each string must equal a value of 200

Comment: Hmm, sounds like I misunderstood your question. Let me think again and make an update.